# SAS Passthrough Query - Inner Query not getting resolved

Tags: sas, pass-through

I need to run a passthrough query on the Netezza DB instead of pulling the records into SAS server. But the query is not running even though syntactically the query is correct. I think pass-through query does not allow this.

```
PROC SQL; 
CONNECT TO &ENGINE AS MYDB ($DBPARM); 
CREATE TABLE TEST AS 
SELECT * FROM CONNECTION TO MYDB
( 
SELECT * FROM MYLIB.M_CV_AUTH_ORDERS  
WHERE SESSION_ID IN (SELECT SESSION_ID FROM MYLIB.M_CV_AUTH_ORDERS  
WHERE ACTIVITY_CD = 'APBP15A') ; 
) 
; 

DISCONNECT FROM MYDB; 
QUIT;
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Inner query is perfectly fine (generally speaking, don't know if Netezza has any special rules).  Does that code work as-is when you execute it in Netezza directly?

Comment: You don't usually need to supply a semicolon within the passthrough brackets. I'm not sure how that affects things, but possibly try by removing it. If that's no help, then Google 'SAS Access RDBMS SASTRACE' for some further debugging options you can enable.

Comment: My apologies for not responding ontime due to being sick. Yes @Joe it runs fine on Netezza DB

Comment: Hope you're better. Then if that works on netezza, I would remove the semicolon as mjsqu notes, and if that doesn't help, perhaps talk to your DBA and see if they can look at the log.

Comment: Thank you Joe and @mjsqu .. The query ran fine after removing ';' and by using connection = global like this from the suggestion of DBA. But not sure what it is. PROC SQL; 
CONNECT TO &ENGINE AS MYDB (&DBPARM connection=global); 
CREATE TABLE TEST AS 
SELECT * FROM CONNECTION TO MYDB
( 
SELECT * FROM MYLIB.M_CV_AUTH_ORDERS  
WHERE SESSION_ID IN (SELECT SESSION_ID FROM MYLIB.M_CV_AUTH_ORDERS  
WHERE ACTIVITY_CD = 'APBP15A') 
) 
; 

DISCONNECT FROM MYDB; 
QUIT;